# Get contents of og:data without jquery

Tags: javascript

So in the head of the page there is:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="assets/css/gfx/skold.png"/>
```

I appreciate that I can use:

```
$('meta[property="og:image"]').attr('content');
```

to get the contents of this, however jQuery is unavailable to me, so how can I do this, bearing in mind it will potentially need to run in IE8, so getElementsByTagName isn't necessarily available either . . .

Look forward to hearing how its done :)

Comment: [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName) has been around since IE 5.5 and was fully supported in IE 6. At least bother to look up browser compatibility tables before you tie your own hands behind your back for no good reason.

Comment: @MattBurland Since he's targetting IE8, he could even use a `querySelector` since he's targetting a `<meta>` with a specific attribute.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need JS.  `querySelectorAll` is available in IE8 [Can I Use querySelectorAll](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector).  And IE8 can use CSS2 query selectors so attribute query selectors are available [Attribute Selectors MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

```
var a = document.querySelectorAll("meta[property='og:image']")[0].content;
console.log(a);
```

or

```
var b = document.querySelector("meta[property='og:image']").content;
console.log(b);
```